# Необходимо прочитать doc/docx файл с помощью Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x

Здравствуйте! Мне необходимо прочитать doc/docx файл с помощью Python 3.6 на винде. Использую python-docx , пытаюсь вывести список параграфов ,но получаю только  "docx.section.Section object at 0x0000000003941BE0" 
"docx.section.Sections object at 0x0000000003941B70"

Как вывести в содержимое, может есть какой нибудь более простой способ.

Comment: Надо прочитать документацию python-docx - это самый действенный способ.

Comment: Если добавлять в вопрос пример документа, код и что нужно получить, то шанс получить ответ резко возрастает